# How to fix "SyntaxError: Unexpected string" error while running tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I have developed unit tests for my react application using jest and enzyme. I am using jest version 25.7.1. When i run tests it fails with below error. I am not sure why its not liking import keyword.

FAIL  src/components/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
D:\Dev\ps-visualizer\ClientApp\node_modules\@svgdotjs\svg.js\src\main.js:2
import './modules/optional/arrange.js'
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@bentley/imodeljs-markup/lib/Markup.js:10:18)
```

Here is my jest configuration in package.json,

```
{
    "browser": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.test.json"
      }
    },
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "\\.(css|less|scss|json)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  }
```

tsconfig is defined like this,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "esnext.asynciterable",
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "stripInternal": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true, 
    "noImplicitAny": true, 
    "strictNullChecks": true, 
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true, 
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true, 
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false, 
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "preserveConstEnums": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well, but with @uifabric/fluent-theme.

Another instance of this issue that I've found: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/facebook/create-react-app/7000/489664785